# Why do i have to call $scope.$digest() here?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I created a directive for showing tooltips:

```
app.directive('tooltip',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attr){
            element.bind('mouseenter',function(e){

                scope.setStyle(e);

            });
        }
    }
});
```

The corresponding `setStyle()` function:

```
$scope.setStyle = function(e){
    $scope.style = {
        position: 'absolute',
        // some other styles
    };

    $scope.$digest();
};
```

`$scope.style` is applied to this:

```
<span ng-style="style">I am a tooltip</span>
```

which is part of my view, handled by the controller who owns `$scope.style`

Why do i have to call `$digest()` in order to apply the changes to `$scope.style`, which was declared and initialized earlier?

Comment: To which elements "$scope.style" is linked ? It would be helpfull if you could make a fiddle for this.

Comment: @Scalpweb
i complemented my post, will provide a fiddle later. End of work now :)

Comment: Source code for `ng-click`: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L41

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Because the callback attached to the `mouseenter` event is outside of angular's scope; angular has no idea when that function runs/ends so the digest cycle is never ran.

Calling `$digest` or `$apply` tells angular to update bindings and fire any watches.

Comment: Thank you very much so far. Are there any disadvantages when solving this problem that way? Should i consider another architecture?

Comment: No, this is what you have to do when outside of angular's scope. A better approach would be to include the `$digest/$apply` call in your directive: `scope.$apply(function(){ scope.setStyle(e); });`

Answer (score 13):

`element.bind()` means listen for specific browser event and execute callback when this event is dispatched on element. Nowhere in this chain of events Angular is included - it does not know that the event happened. Therefore you must tell it about the event explicitly. However, in most cases you should use `$scope.$apply()` not `$scope.$digest()`, especially when you're not sure about it.

Here is more appropriate code for your situation:

```
app.directive('tooltip',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attr){
            element.bind('mouseenter',function(e){
                scope.setStyle(e);
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and `setStyle()`:

```
$scope.setStyle = function(e){
    $scope.style = {
        position: 'absolute',
        // some other styles
    };
};
```

Comment: $scope.$apply() calls $rootScope.$digest(), so indeed you probably want to either call $scope.$apply() or $rootScope.$digest(). Calling $scope.$digest() means you're restricting the digest to the local scope.

Answer (score 1):

$scope.apply() has two implementations, one that has no arguments and other one takes a function as argument, evaluates it and trigger digest(). Using the latter one has advantages as it wraps up your function in try/catch clause which is handled by $exceptionHandler service.

Although, you can do like this as well:

```
$scope.$apply(scope.setStyle(e));
```

This will wrap your function call to apply and auto triggers the digest.

Comment: Technically this is not wrapping your `setStyle` call inside the $apply invocation. `setStyle` returns and passes its return value to $apply. It'll still work in most cases, but it might be a bit misleading.